# Visual Studio Git: Pull Request merge removes file unexpectedly

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am relatively new to Git, so bear with this probable very newbish question.  First the scenario:

1. Created a branch from our dev branch in project A of our solution.
2. Worked on it for a day.
3. In the meantime others had branched off and worked in Project B and merged back into dev using our Pull Request (PR) process.
4. Unwittingly, I submitted a PR request to merge my code.
5. My merge deleted files that those working on project B had created.
6. Project B and Project A had absolutely no relationship to each other, other than being part of the same solution.

My question is why did my merge delete the files from Project B?

1. I made absolutely no reference to their files.
2. Their changes were later than mine.

I obviously made a naive assumption that Git would merge my changes without affected their code because there was zero overlap.  I thought that was one of the strengths of DVCS.

What underlying concept am I missing?

Comment: What command(s) did you execute?

Comment: Used the Visual Studio GUI, so not sure of the exact commands as relates to the CLI, but I did a branch from local dev repository (after dev was synced) and then commit then sync (the sync is basically a pull then a push as far as I know).  I did not remerge dev into my branch, again due to my naivete.

Comment: @Gustyn You said that you raised a Pull Request. In your above description, I couldn't see that. ?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your scenario but cannot see the issue. Can you check if these files do exist in Dev branch before you merge your code?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes I did a pull request after the sync, then a merge happened from there into dev.  Yes we confirmed that the files were in dev before we merged the branch into dev.

Comment: Are the changes on other files in project B kept in dev branch after merge?